# Codeigniter - insert and rename the upload image file to auto-increment ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I try to rename the upload images (3 images) and then insert to mysql.
The problem is, `$this->db->insert_id();` has to put after the insert query and the `$config['file_name']` has to put before uploaded.
How should I rename to auto-id then upload and insert?

```
                $config['upload_path']          = 'images/location';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 2048; //2048KB = 2MB
                $config['max_width']            = 2000;
                $config['max_height']           = 1500;



                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'); 
                $data_upl['image1'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');

                $this->upload->do_upload('userfile2');
                $data_upl['image2'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');

                $this->upload->do_upload('userfile3');
                $data_upl['image3'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');

                $data = array(
                   'location_pic' => $data_upl['image1'],
                   'location_pic2' => $data_upl['image2'],
                   'location_pic3' => $data_upl['image3']
                );

                $this->db->insert('oav_event', $data);

                $get_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                $config['file_name'] = "id".$get_id;

                $this->load->view('admin/success', $data_upl);
```

Comment: You should not do this, because CI will not recognize the `id` before insert, why do you want to append `id` to `file_name`?

Comment: it's my boss's requirement

Comment: Problem is you have 3 files and only 1 id. Rename 3 files using same name in same folder is impossible by any operating system